# remote rejected git push error while uploading

Tags: git, open-source, repository

Has anyone seen this error before while doing a git push? Any tips to debug or overcome the error?

```
mkdir opensource && cd opensource
git clone git://git.qinc.com/platform/vendor/q-opensource/wcn/prime.git
cd prime
git checkout -b jb_2.5 origin/jb_2.5
git cherry-pick -x ..7174961054435d3ae9d233c81227b0715cfc1715
git push ssh://review-android.qinc.com:29418/platform/vendor/q-opensource/wcn/prime.git jb_2.5:refs/for/jb_2.5

test@wcn-linux5:/local/mnt2/workspace2/test/LA_builds/opensource_JB2.5/prime$ git push ssh://review-android.qinc.com:29418/platform/vendor/q-opensource/wlan/prime.git jb_2.5:refs/for/jb_2.5
Enter passphrase for key '/usr2/test/.ssh/id_rsa':
Counting objects: 662, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (100/100), done.
Writing objects: 100% (148/148), 534.35 KiB, done.
Total 148 (delta 88), reused 97 (delta 47)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (88/88)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done   
remote: (W) be1d372: no files changed, was rebased
To ssh://review-android.qinc.com:29418/platform/vendor/q-opensource/wlan/prime.git
! [remote rejected] jb_2.5 -> refs/for/jb_2.5 (no changes made)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://review-android.qinc.com:29418/platform/vendor/q-opensource/wlan/prime.git'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a push that you didn't pull before you push your changes, so it would overwrite the master branch. You should pull the master branch and then merge with your changeset after you can push the whole.

Alternatively if you have permission you can use push -f, however it kill anyone else's push.

Comment: the clone command is doing the pull of the master branch and then we cherrypicked the changes and I can see those cherrypick changes in my git log...so,where is the problem?